# is there a way to put condition on constant value parameter in C++ template specialization?

Tags: c++, templates

is there's a way to constrain the integral template parameter as specialization instead of this code redundancy ?

```
// redundant code

template <int N>
struct A {};
template <>
struct A <0> {};
template <>
struct A <1> {};

// what i want is some thing like this

template <int N>
struct A {};

template <>
struct A <N < 2> {};
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use [SFINAE](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/sfinae)="Substitution Failure Is Not An Error". There are several ways this could be done here, for example

```
template<int N, typename E=void>
struct A { /* ... */ };     // general type

template<int N>
struct A<N, std::enable_if_t<(N<2)> >
{ /* ... */ };              // specialisation for N<2
```

Note that `std::enable_if_t<>` is a C++14 type, it's equivalent to

```
template<bool C, typename T=void>
using enable_if_t = typename std::enable_if<C,T>::type;
```

**How does it work?** The definition of `std::enable_if` is similar to

```
template<bool C, typename T=void>
struct enable_if { using type=T; };

template<typename T>
struct enable_if<false,T> {};
```

In particular, there is no sub-type `enable_if::type` in case the condition `C` is false. Thus in the above specialisation `enable_if_t<(N<2)>` expands to a valid type (`void`) only for `N<2`. For `N>=2`, we have substitution failure, since `enable_if<(N<2)>::type` does not exist. C++ allows such failure, but simply ignores the resulting (invalid) code.

Answer (score 2):

You could add a second template parameter, with a default value that selects the specialization you want:

```
template <int N, bool = (N < 2)>
struct A {
    // code for N>=2 case
};

template <int N>
struct A<N, true> {
    // code for N<2 case
};
```

(You don't need to name the second parameter since you'll never be referring to it explicitly.)