# Define and declare a const std::array with constexpr if

Tags: c++, arrays, stl, containers, constexpr

I am trying to implement Gauss-Legendre quadrature, and I want a templated function
that takes the number of points as a template parameter.
Right now I have this:

```cpp
template<int number_of_quadrature_points>
double gaussian_quadrature_integral_core(double (*f)(double), double from, double to){
    double scaling_factor = (to-from)/2;   
    double average_factor = (from+to)/2;
    std::array<double, number_of_quadrature_points> factors;
    std::array<double, number_of_quadrature_points> points;
    if constexpr(number_of_quadrature_points == 2){
        factors = {1, 1};
        points = {-1.0/sqrt(3), 1.0/sqrt(3)};
    }
    if constexpr(number_of_quadrature_points == 3){
        factors = {5.0/9.0, 8.0/9.0, 5.0/9.0};
        points = {-sqrt(3.0/5.0), 0, sqrt(3.0/5.0)};
    }
    
    double sum = 0;

    for(int i = 0; i < number_of_quadrature_points; i++){
        sum += factors.at(i)*((*f)(scaling_factor*points.at(i)+average_factor));
    }

    sum *= scaling_factor;
    return sum;
}
```

As you see, when the template parameter changes, not only the array size changes, but also the content is changed, but for a given size the content is well known. For this reason I think it would be better if the std::arrays were const static, as the function is called many times.

Right now I have only managed to use if constexpr to declare the array, but how can I use it both to define and declare the array so It is visible outside the if constexpr scope and the arrays are only defined once?

Comment: What happens if someone calls your function with N different from 2 or 3? `if constexpr` are great, but I would go for a specialized template in that case (for the factors/points selection).

Comment: @Cedric this is indeed a problem, right now I just wanted to do a static assert, but I will reconsider it as Your comment made me aware such a solution might not be elegant.

Answer (score 1):

Adding two helper functions could be enough (if you're using C++20):

```
template<unsigned N>
constexpr auto init_factors() {
    std::array<double, N> rv;
    if constexpr(N == 2){
        rv = {1., 1.};
    } else {
        rv = {5.0/9.0, 8.0/9.0, 5.0/9.0};
    }
    return rv;
}

template<unsigned N>
constexpr auto init_points() {
    std::array<double, N> rv;
    if constexpr(N == 2){
        rv = {-1.0/std::sqrt(3.), 1.0/std::sqrt(3.)};
    } else {
        rv = {-std::sqrt(3.0/5.0), 0, std::sqrt(3.0/5.0)};
    }
    return rv;
}

template<unsigned number_of_quadrature_points>
double gaussian_quadrature_integral_core(double (*f)(double), double from,
                                                              double to)
{
    static constexpr auto factors = init_factors<number_of_quadrature_points>();
    static constexpr auto points = init_points<number_of_quadrature_points>();
[...]
```

To prevent usage with the wrong number of points, you could add a `static_assert`

```
template<unsigned number_of_quadrature_points>
double
gaussian_quadrature_integral_core(double (*f)(double), double from,
                                                       double to)
{
    static_assert(number_of_quadrature_points==2||number_of_quadrature_points==3);
```

...or prevent matching using SFINAE if you want to make a specialization later:

```
#include <type_traits>

template<unsigned number_of_quadrature_points>
std::enable_if_t<number_of_quadrature_points==2||number_of_quadrature_points==3,
                 double>
gaussian_quadrature_integral_core(double (*f)(double), double from,
                                                       double to)
{
```

Comment: Something like this also came to my mind, but I was thinking if it was possible without the helper functions. It is still a good solution though, thank you.

Comment: @KarolSzustakowski Use lambdas if you prefer them.

Answer (score 1):

You might have template variable:

```
template <std::size_t N>
static constexpr std::array<double, N> factors;

template <std::size_t N>
static constexpr std::array<double, N> points;

template <>
constexpr std::array<double, 2> factors<2>{{1, 1}};
template <>
constexpr std::array<double, 2> points<2>{{-1.0 / sqrt(3), 1.0 / sqrt(3)}};

template <>
constexpr std::array<double, 3> factors<3>{{5.0 / 9.0, 8.0 / 9.0, 5.0 / 9.0}};
template <>
constexpr std::array<double, 3> points<3>{{-sqrt(3.0 / 5.0), 0, sqrt(3.0 / 5.0)}};
```

and then

```
template<int number_of_quadrature_points>
double gaussian_quadrature_integral_core(double (*f)(double), double from, double to)
{
    const double scaling_factor = (to - from) / 2;   
    const double average_factor = (from + to) / 2;
    double sum = 0;

    for(int i = 0; i < number_of_quadrature_points; i++){
        sum += factors<number_of_quadrature_points>[i]
           * ((*f)(scaling_factor * points<number_of_quadrature_points>[i] + average_factor));
    }

    sum *= scaling_factor;
    return sum;
}
```

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a41a883773ac9f3b)

Notice that you have to replace `constexpr` by `const` if you don't have constexpr `sqrt` (which `std::` isn't).

Comment: ... and it works even in C++14, which is nice.

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like in this topic:
[is there a way to put condition on constant value parameter in C++ template specialization?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44190653/is-there-a-way-to-put-condition-on-constant-value-parameter-in-c-template-spec)

So we are creating two template specialisations using [std::enable_if](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/enable_if) and SFINAE. We differentiate them by template parameter *number_of_quadrature_points*. This way we have global parameters which does not have to be defined and instantiated multiple times. This code compiles using c++17.

Also I suggest to use modern approach with [std::function<>](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function) instead of pointer to function.

```
#include <array>
#include <cmath>
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>

template<int number_of_quadrature_points, typename E=void>
struct gaussian_quadrature_params
{

};

template<int number_of_quadrature_points>
struct gaussian_quadrature_params<number_of_quadrature_points, std::enable_if_t<(number_of_quadrature_points==2)> >
{
    constexpr static const std::array<double, number_of_quadrature_points> factors = {1, 1};
    constexpr static const std::array<double, number_of_quadrature_points> points = {-1.0/sqrt(3), 1.0/sqrt(3)};
};

template<int number_of_quadrature_points>
struct gaussian_quadrature_params<number_of_quadrature_points, std::enable_if_t<(number_of_quadrature_points==3)> >
{
    constexpr static const std::array<double, number_of_quadrature_points> factors = {5.0/9.0, 8.0/9.0, 5.0/9.0};
    constexpr static const std::array<double, number_of_quadrature_points> points = {-sqrt(3.0/5.0), 0, sqrt(3.0/5.0)};
};


double f(double x)
{
    return x;
}


template<int number_of_quadrature_points>
double gaussian_quadrature_integral_core(std::function<double(double)> f, double from, double to){
    double scaling_factor = (to-from)/2;   
    double average_factor = (from+to)/2;
    
    double sum = 0;

    for(int i = 0; i < number_of_quadrature_points; i++){
        sum += gaussian_quadrature_params<number_of_quadrature_points>::factors.at(i)*(f(scaling_factor*gaussian_quadrature_params<number_of_quadrature_points>::points.at(i)+average_factor));
    }

    sum *= scaling_factor;
    return sum;
}

int main()
{
   std::cout << gaussian_quadrature_integral_core<2>(f, -1.0, 1.0) << std::endl;
   std::cout << gaussian_quadrature_integral_core<3>(f, -1.0, 1.0) << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: You might simply have specialization for `template<> struct gaussian_quadrature_params<2>` with enabler (you can keep enabler to allow real formula (as odd numbers greater than 42)).

Answer (score 0):

How about

```
// N: number_of_quadrature_points
template<int N>
double gaussian_quadrature_integral_core(double (*f)(double), double from, double to)
{
    constexpr std::array<double, N> factors = []()
        ->std::array<double, N>{
        if constexpr(N == 2)
            return {1.0, 1.0};
        else if constexpr(N == 3)
            return {5.0 / 9.0, 8.0 / 9.0, 5.0 / 9.0};
        // ... other N cases
    }();

    constexpr std::array<double, N> points= []()->auto{
        if constexpr(N == 2)
            return std::array<double, N>{-1.0 / std::sqrt(3), 1.0 / std::sqrt(3)};
        else if constexpr(N == 3)
            return std::array<double, N>{-std::sqrt(3.0 / 5.0), 0, std::sqrt(3.0 / 5.0)};
        // ... other N cases
    }();

    double scaling_factor = (to - from) / 2;
    double average_factor = (from + to) / 2;
    double sum = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
        sum += factors.at(i)*((*f)(scaling_factor * points.at(i) + average_factor));

    sum *= scaling_factor;
    return sum;
}
```

which declare and define the arrays using `if constexpr`.